# New Linux/Ubuntu Missing a .ko file WiFI adapter driver rtl8822b

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

I am a new user to Linux and Ubuntu and even to Windows to be honest so this might not make sense in general and i wouldn't say that I'm very technical yet when it comes to understanding everything.

I was trying to install de drivers of an USB Wifi adapter, extracted all the files, made their own directories and built the driver, following all instructions from my USB Wifi adapter's CD manual with a few modifications since the manual shows a diferent file, the last step is where it tells me to execute the command to load it with a .ko  kernel object(?) file.

To my understanding it makes the .o and the .c files work in the folders i just extracted and "built" yet i cant find it, in the manual it resembles the number of the USB driver yet the closest that there is its a .mk file named rtl8822b.mk i try to run it and it says that its not compatible, should i modify the .mk file to a .ko or did something go wrong?

Here are the steps i took.

```
user@pc:~/Documents$ tar vxzf rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959.tar.gz
```

Then

```
~/Documents$ cd rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
```

Then did a

```
sudo make
```

after doing that something that stood out to me was

```
Documents/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2190:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 2190 |   set_fs(get_ds());
      |          ^~~~~~
      |          get_da
```

"Get ds, did you mean get_da?" Im still wondering if some of these errors were the reason the .ko file didnt show up? I don't know, I'm still a couple days into Ubuntu and maybe i`m missing something but i was wondering if any could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to install drivers from [Cilynx's GitHub repo for RTL88x2BU drivers](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU).

As detailed in the repo, you can install the drivers using [DKMS installation method](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU#dkms-installation):

```
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i hope i can keep learning how to use Ubuntu and any other Linux distro, cheers.

Comment: @foam I'm glad that it worked out for you. Now in regards to learning Ubuntu and Linux in general, well you'll find all the help you would need, on AskUbuntu and other Linux forums, so feel free to just ask :)